# What is the difference between this two regarding differentiability over $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f'_x(x,0)=f'_x(0,0),\  \lim_{y \to 0}f'_y(0,y)=f'_y(0,0)
$$
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f'_x(x,y)=f'_x(0,0),\ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f'_y(x,y)=f'_y(0,0)
$$
also, which of this two is equivalent to $f$ being differentiable at $(0,0)$ and why?

Comment: None, because differentiability at $(0,0)$ does not imply even that $f_x'(x,y)$, $f_y'(x,y)$ exist anywhere except at $(0,0)$. In fact, it doesn't imply even that $f$ is continuous anywhere except at $(0,0)$. Say $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2+y^2&x,y\in\mathbb Q\\-(x^2+y^2)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Can you tell me which one of the two is the sufficient condition of   being differentiable at (0,0) ?

Comment: I would prefer that you try to figure it yourself by analyzing a suitable function  such as $f(x, y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$.